# Deveríamos desconectar a tag [connection]?

Tags: debate, tags

Editei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171056/18246) antes e a primeira coisa que pensei foi retirar a tag [connection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection) dela. Antes disso, [abri a página da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection) e me deparei com **17 perguntas** utilizando-a.

Nós já temos a tag [conexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conex%c3%a3o) com **83 perguntas**.

Não seria melhor trocarmos nestas 17 perguntas a tag [connection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection) por [conexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conex%c3%a3o)?

Por mim eu já teria o feito, mas tenho receio que seja esforço jogado fora, uma vez que os AP's ainda poderão usar essa tag e continuaremos com o mesmo "problema".

O que vocês acham?

Comment: jbueno se já é um erro comum o melhor é criar um sinónimo e fica o assunto resolvido.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não sei se é muito comum. São só 17 perguntas que existem hoje, só que também não sei se alguém editou as perguntas pra ter só 17.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pois foi o que eu disse :p

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah sim, eu me confundi antes também. Nem sabia que dava pra criar tags com acento no nome =D

Comment: @jbueno a mim parece-me coisa que vá acontecer mais vezes.

Comment: No caso a sugestão é sinonimizar? será que não estão sendo usados em contextos diferentes (mesmo que alguns ultrapassem o bom uso)? Se houver clareza que é mesmo a mesma coisa (nem sempre é o que parece) dá pra mesclá-las.

Comment: @bigown Vou tentar ler algumas dessas perguntas e editar pra ver se são sobre a mesma coisa. Por cima, deu a entender que a maioria era sobre conexão com o banco, mas tem que ver melhor. De qualquer forma, "conexão" por si próprio já é um termo bem amplo.

Comment: Transforma-la em sinônimo seria o melhor a se fazer, por exemplo, se eu tivesse uma pergunta sobre alguma coisa que envolve o `Connection` do java, certamente usaria essa tag para complementar as outras. Fica aqui a minha opinião.

Comment: Todas as perguntas com a tag [tag:connection] foram removidas. Basta agora transformar connection em sinônimo de conexão.